# How do I grant root access to a user application?

Tags: c++, linux, root

I have a user-level C++ test application running on a linux mobile device. One of the test involves enabling/disabling printer paper sensor which requires root privileges writing on a device file. Is there a way to grant my application that kind of privilege? If none, is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do,

as `root` execute:

```
chown -v root:root /path/to/yourapp
chmod -v 4755 /path/to/yourapp
```

or alternatively

```
chmod -v u+s /path/to/yourapp
```

or alternatively

```
man chmod
```

This will **not work with scripts**. And yes, you should take seriously what **jdizzle** said about dropping unnecessary privileges.

Another way to solve this is to make the user who runs the application a member of the group that owns the device file. For example,

```
ls -la /dev/devicefile
crw-rw---- 1 root printer 4, 0 may  6 10:56 /dev/devicefile
```

members of the `printer` group can read and write to the device, so you just need to add `joe` to the `printer` group (and restart the session).

```
gpasswd -a joe printer
```

If you need to adjust the devicefile permissions, you probably will need to edit udev rules to make it permanent. But `chmod` should work too.

Other options worth investigating: [`setcap(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap) (nice guide [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Using_File_Capabilities_Instead_Of_Setuid)) and [`sudo(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).

Answer (score 2):

You can set the program setuid root, which means it will always run as root even when run by a user.  This typically requires special care to drop privileges inside the program once the necessary actions requiring root access are completed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a helper program, itself setuid root -or with appropriate capabilities, or started thru `sudo`- which communicate with the printer. Your main application would fork & exec that program and communicate with it thru pipes, so it should not be itself running as root.

The helper program would be a simple executable (with appropriate capabilities) which would only be started by your main application (not directly by the user) and communicate with it thru pipes or program arguments, etc.

A lot of graphical administrative programs are done likewise: the graphical part is a program separated from the administrative part, and they communicate appropriately. Only the administrative program (usually existing command line programs like `adduser`) need special privilege.

Comment: what do you mean by helper program? Can you give me a simple example? :D

Answer (score -3):

you should definitey try to avoid running your program as "root", as this would not only allow your program to read/write /dev/sensordevice but it would grant access to virtually everything on your system (including the ability to completely brick it)

you should therefore try to add fine-grained access to just the ressource you need, using proper groups and making sure that your device-file grants your group write access.
see (e.g.) [udev](http://wiki.debian.org/udev) on how to write a proper udev rule, that grants write access for a certain device to a given group.