# Working around sudo in shell script child process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

So the reason I am asking this is because I'm running two programs simultaneously that are persistent, on the child process a programm is running that requires sudo rights.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Name the file:"
read filename
while [[ 1 -lt 2 ]]
do
 if [ -f /home/max/dump/$filename.eth ]; then
  echo "File already exist."
  read filename
 else
  break
 fi
done 
#Now calling a new terminal for dumping

gnome-terminal --title="tcpdump" -e "sh /home/max/dump/dump.sh  $filename.eth"
ping -c 1 0 > /dev/null **Waiting for tcpdump to create file**
#Packet analysis program is being executed
```

## Script dump.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
echo password | sudo tcpdump -i 2 -s 60000 -w /home/max/dump/$filename -U 
host 192.168.3.2
#Sudo still asks me for my password though password is piped into stdin
```

Comment: You add root access to the executable for a specific user, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476154/how-do-i-grant-root-access-to-a-user-application . Alternatively, you could run the application as user, which is a member of a group which owns the network adapter.

Comment: Ok, thanks I didn't know how this is done with chmod but now it's obvious ;) . I messed with visudo  not to ask for the root password before, but this I think is more convenient.